# How to send Recurring Monthly,Weekly emails based on date in php

Tags: php, email

I need to send recurring emails for every month,week according to user subscription,while sending mails i have to calculate date intervals from registered date.

I have used below code,

```
$30_day_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE reminder = 1 AND date
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
```

This query work for sending the email out every 30 days after the initial Date of Service,

I have planned to run this in Cron.

Please Suggest.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: hi, we're not here to write your code for you, but start by breaking it down into the various steps. You'll need something to `create the email` - filling it with the necessary information, to `send the email` to a specific address and something to `schedule the email` which could be cron, as you suggest... then maybe you'll need something to `decide whether the email should be sent`.  there are *LOTS* of tutorials on sending emails through PHP on the internet... :)

Comment: Hi i am not asking how to send the email,i need the recurring query to work for every month.

Comment: OK, so check the answer below for scheduling a script.  then that script should work out who should receive the email.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what to put in your crontab file to run the script every monday at midnight.

```
# crontab -e
0 0 * * 1 /usr/local/bin/php /home/ryan/myscript.php
```

You can generate any cron sequence you need at this website: 
http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/cron-generator.shtml